# Typescript Type incompatability on Beacon SDK

Tags: beacon

I'm injecting a environment variable to feed which network should my app connect to (mainnet or a testnet)

This is some pseudo code:

```
import { Network, NetworkType,  } from '@airgap/beacon-sdk';

// NOTE: process.env.LOGGEDOUT_TEZOS_NETWORK = 'mainnet';

const network: Network =  network = {
  type: (process.env.LOGGEDOUT_TEZOS_NETWORK as NetworkType), // this casting is necessary because this env variable is a string and Network expects NetworkType
  name: process.env.LOGGEDOUT_TEZOS_NETWORK,
  rpcUrl: getInitialRandomNode().value,
};

wallet = new BeaconWallet({
  name: 'versum',
  preferredNetwork: network.type,
});
```

the above example is a snippet the allows for either `mainnet` or some `testnet` to be automatically feed to the wallet (for our production/test environments)

`preferredNetwork: network.type` gives me `Type 'NetworkType' is not assignable to type 'NetworkType | undefined'`
because on `Network` `type` is mandatory and on `preferredNetwork` its optional.

Is this a type incompatibility? can this be resolved with casting?

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, here is a [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/embed/long-voice-n16mhr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

I don't see any tsconfig that could cause that error message. Maybe the ide lsp crashed and is giving outdated results?